# Jacobi's matric formulation for tensors

Tags: general-relativity, linear-algebra

Hi I am trying to derive the E field equation and am stuck using the [Jacobi formula](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi%27s_formula), is this correct: $$\delta \det g_{\mu \nu} = Tr(ADJ(g_{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu})=\det(g_{\mu\nu})Tr(g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu \nu}) $$ Then how can we remove the trace, or should it be: $$\delta \det g_{\mu \nu} =\det(g_{\mu\nu})Tr(g^{-1}\delta g)=\det(g_{\mu\nu})(g\delta g)^{\mu}_{\mu}=\det(g_{\mu\nu})(g\delta g)^{\mu}_{\mu}=\det(g_{\mu\nu})(g^{\mu\nu}\delta g_{\mu\nu}) $$

Answer (score 4):

You should be careful not to mix symbolic and index notation. $ \text{Tr}(g^{\mu \nu}\delta g_{\mu \nu}) $ does not make sense since $g^{\mu \nu}\delta g_{\mu \nu}$ is just a number. The correct symbolic notation would be:

$$\delta \text{det}(\mathbf{g})=\text{Tr}(\text{adj}(\mathbf{g})\delta \mathbf{g})=\text{det}(\mathbf{g})\text{Tr}(\mathbf{g}^{-T}\delta \mathbf{g}))$$ since $\text{adj}(\mathbf{g})=\text{det}(\mathbf{g})\mathbf{g}^{-T}$. Now you can transform to index notation and Einstein convention:
$$\delta \text{det}(g_{\mu \nu})=\text{det}(g_{\mu \nu})(g^{\mu \nu} \delta g_{\mu \nu}) $$